# How to prevent certain input to React Native's TextInput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to disable input of certain characters in my TextInput. If I make the input controlled and set value by listening to onKeyPress, the component flickers, as [warned](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#value) in the React Native docs. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: what is your requirement of textinput? only digits?, alphanumeric ?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the TextInput by using onChangeText is working just fine for me.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

export default class PizzaTranslator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      text: ''
    };
  }

  changeText(text) {
    let newText = text.replace("a", "b");
    this.setState({ text: newText });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{padding: 10}}>
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="Type here!"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.changeText(text)}
          value={this.state.text}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

You would just need to replace those characters with nothing in the `changeText` function.

Comment: While this technique can work, it can also lead to some weird insert caret behavior, like constantly moving the caret to the end of the input even when you're editing a character that isn't at the end.

Comment: onChangeText has been the same as other events. Flickering is always there.

Comment: I would assume that the flickering is a whole other issue. Try using onChange and e.preventDefault();, live with it: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23578 or make the changes after submit / on validation.

Comment: @TemporaryName I have tried using onChange, but I can't detect backspace using it, as I get empty string in event.nativeEvent.text. That's why I was using onKeyPress.

Comment: @mohsinulhaq What do you need to detect backspace for? You could use a separate handler for that if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Yeah, I am creating a customized OTP component. Detecting backspace with onKeyPress again creates the flickering issue as the input goes out of sync for a moment with the control value as noted in the comment your link: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23578#issuecomment-521821027

Comment: Maybe I can't help you. Last thing I would consider is using onChangeText for sanitizing input and onKeyPress for whatever backspace needs to do (but for nothing else).